# How can I add a character into a specified position into string in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a varchar field like:

```
195500
122222200
```

I need to change these values to:

```
1955.00
1222222.00
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to add a '.' before the last two digits of your values you can do:

```
SELECT substring(code,0,len(code)-1)+'.'+substring(code,len(code)-1,len(code))
FROM table1;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e34c/3)</kbd>

Answer (score 33):

`try this`

```
Declare @s varchar(50) = '1234567812333445'
Select Stuff(@s, Len(@s)-1, 0, '.')
--> 12345678123334.45
```

[fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5169d/2)

Answer (score 21):

Query:

```
SELECT col,
       LEFT(col,len(col)-2) + '.' + RIGHT(col,2) as newcol
FROM Table1
```

Result:

```
|       COL |     NEWCOL |
|-----------|------------|
|    195500 |    1955.00 |
| 122222200 | 1222222.00 |
```

Comment: I'd use `RIGHT(col, 2)` since theres no guarantee the value is always `00`

Comment: This is an excellent answer, glad you wrote it ... 5 years ago? Wow, coming in handy in 2018!

Comment: Good stuff dontt age:))

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 
   Col,
   REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(Col), 1, 2, LEFT(REVERSE(Col), 2)+'.'))
from YourTable
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ea27/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #T ( Value VARCHAR(20) )
INSERT INTO #T ( Value ) VALUES ( 195500 ), ( 122222200)

SELECT 
    Value
,   NewValue = CONVERT(DECIMAL(17,2),CONVERT(DECIMAL,Value) / 100)
FROM #T

|     Value |   NewValue |
|-----------|------------|
|    195500 |    1955.00 |
| 122222200 | 1222222.00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try :
select reverse(stuff(reverse(columnName),3,0,'.') ) from yourTable

Answer (score 0):

Ran into something similar and came up with this, could probably change this to a function/SP to make it reusable. Scenario faced was inserting a specified character at different positions within the string, for a certain number of times.

```
/*
 --- passed in string or column,  N'C4CB6B22250B'
 --- desired output, C4:CB:6B:22:25:0D
 --- Test values 
 --- declare @strToChange varchar(50) = N'C4:CB:6B:22:25:0B'
 --- declare @strToChange varchar(50) = N'C4CB6B22250B'
*/


declare @strToChange varchar(50) = N'C4CB6B22250B'
IF(SELECT LEN(@strToChange) - LEN(REPLACE(@strToChange, ':', ''))) > 0
    BEGIN
        ---returns count of specified char
        SELECT LEN(@strToChange) - LEN(REPLACE(@strToChange, ':', ''))
    END
        ELSE
    BEGIN
        declare @charCount int = 5; --# of times to insert the char
        declare @shiftPosition int = 2; -- inital insertion shift
        While(@charCount > 0)
            begin
            SET @strToChange = LEFT(@strToChange,len(@strToChange)- @shiftPosition) + ':' + RIGHT(@strToChange,@shiftPosition)
            SET @charCount = @charCount - 1 --decrement charCount for each added char
            SET @shiftPosition = @shiftPosition + 3 ---increment shift position by 3 for the new char and the chars that were already there
        end
    SELECT @strToChange
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Please see the following code. You can choose the symbols and index in variable.

```
 declare @index int,@sym varchar(10)
 set @sym='#'
 set @index=2
 select left(195500,@index) +''+@sym+''+right(195500,len(195500)-@index)
```

Comment: You can add symbols on specific positions

Answer (score -3):

declare @a varchar(10) = 'aaa'
select concat(@a,'.00')