# Insert character into Column Data

Tags: sql

I have an existing table that contains numerical data within a column (`column1` for example).

The data consists of 5 to 9 characters:

```
ex. 12345
    1234567
    123456789
```

I need to insert a comma before the last 3 characters:

```
ex. 12,345
    1234,567
    123456,789
```

This would be on a SQL Server.

Comment: SQL has a variety of functions for editing strings.  What have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a character into a specified position into string in SQL SERVER?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121323/how-can-i-add-a-character-into-a-specified-position-into-string-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
DECLARE @SomeNumber BIGINT
SET @SomeNumber = 1234567891234

SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,@SomeNumber),1), '.00','')
```

First we convert the data to the datatype MONEY, this way we get the comma at the thousands:

```
CONVERT(MONEY,@SomeNumber)
```

Then we convert the MONEY datatype to VARCHAR datatype:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,@SomeNumber),1)
```

Then we remove the ".00" from the string by using the REPLACE function and replacing it with an empty string '':

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,@SomeNumber),1), '.00','')
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply this. Not a SQL guy and have no idea why I'm doing this lol.

Comment: @Andrew I hope the above explanation helped a bit. Perhaps you can show me your SQL code you are writing then I can direct you better.